# All-Solution ILP problems with SCIP

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, scip

I am currently using SCIP for academic research. I met an insufficient memory error when I was trying to get all solutions of an ILP instance. I wonder if there is any setting that can output the solution immediately when the solver finds it instead of keeping all solutions in memory.

Comment: What are the exact steps you take so far for solution counting, and what memory limit do you have? By intercepting the code in cons_countsol.c that stores a sparse solution, and printing all the represented solutions instead, it might be easily achievable.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Gregor. The exact steps I took were 1) read xxx.lp, 2) set emphasis counter, 3) set constraints countsols collect TRUE, 4) count. And the memory limit is 15G. The lp file contains about 20 variables and 100 constraints.